# UIImagePickerViewController - Disable Auto-Focus / Tap-to-Focus box in iPhone 4?

Tags: ios4, iphone-4

Is it possible to disable Auto-Focus / Tap-to-Focus box in iPhone 4 (I'm using UIImagePickerViewController to show the camera)?